# Eureka Forms broken after Swift 4.1 Update

Tags: swift, eureka-forms, swift4.1

I just updated to Swift 4.1 and Eureka Forms is broken. I am trying to fix it myself, but I am not sure where to start. Does any one know if the library authors have fixed this yet? I didn't see any issues posted about it. The errors I get are as follows:
Type 'Section' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection'

Candidate has non-matching type '(Section) -> Void' [with SubSequence = Section.SubSequence]

Candidate has non-matching type 'S' [with SubSequence = Section.SubSequence]

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't the best fix I found that if I went to the latest release and copied over the source file and overwrite the old source file it compiles no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Eureka 4.1.1 works with Swift 4.1. Make sure your dependency manager is installing the latest version.

Comment: Not working for me. I tried to install Eureka 4.1.1 this way:    pod 'Eureka', '~> 4.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, spent about 5 minutes to find out that for some reason in my project (although the project was using the Swift 4.1 compiler) That Eureka POD was not, even though it was using 4.1.1 release. I simply went into the Pods project, selected the Eureka target, updated it to swift 4.1, and now it compiles just fine.